# How to accept a deletion but keep the comment on it in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, comments, change-tracking

If I have a tracked deletion and there is a comment on it, accepting the deletion will remove the comment as well.

[image: screenshot showing deletion with comment]

The above action results in:

[image: screenshot showing actual result - comment has been removed]

Is there any way to accept the deletion while keeping the comment(s) around? Such that I can have the following result.

[image: screenshot showing expected result - comment remains after deletion accepted]

For the above, I used the workaround of *rejecting* the deletion of the text, then manually performing an *untracked* deletion of the same text in parts (`deleted`, `text`, `with some`) so that the comment remains.

I am using Microsoft Office Standard 2010. I have tried hiding comments and then accepting deletion. It didn't help as the hidden comment was deleted anyway.